JQuery UI not showing tooltip (serializing toop tip not working)
I have used Jquery UI before and tooltips without issue.
This time for some reason I cant get them to work.
I am trying to get a tooltip to show on only 1 element if the mouse is hovered over it.
Here is the code:


$("#barracks").tooltip({
  disabled: true
});
$(document).click(function() {
  if ($("#barracks").tooltip("option", "disabled")) {
    $("#barracks").tooltip("enable");
    $("#barracks").tooltip("open");
    $("#barracks").off("mouseleave focusout");
  } else {
    $("#barracks").tooltip("close");
    $("#barracks").tooltip("disable");
  }
});
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://www. domain .com/adminp/occur/assets/img/soldier.jpg" id="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded float-start max-width: 100%;" alt="infantry" title="Infantry">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://www. domain .com/adminp/occur/assets/img/gunner.jpg" id="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block max-width: 100%;" alt="gunner" title="Gunner">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://www. domain .com/adminp/occur/assets/img/pilot.jpg" id="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block max-width: 100%;" alt="pilot" title="Pilot">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://www. domain .com/adminp/occur/assets/img/astronaut.jpg" id="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded float-end max-width: 100%;" alt="astronaut" title="Astronaut">
</div>



The Infrantry tooltip works, but not the other 3. Rest tooltips are not displaying

IDs should be unique, having multiple id="barracks" is invalid HTML. If you want to apply something to multiple elements, have a look at classes.

id consider as unique identifier per element when used in javascript/Jquery for event handling over an element.
class consider as group identifier when used in javascript/Jquery for event handling over a group of element.
Your issue is you have used same id to deal with multiple tooltip and hense its over-writing the previously created one.And you are getting only one tool-tip in last.
Conver id to class and you are good to go
Working snippet:


$(".barracks").tooltip({
  disabled: true
});
$(document).click(function() {
  if ($(".barracks").tooltip("option", "disabled")) {
    $(".barracks").tooltip("enable");
    $(".barracks").tooltip("open");
    $(".barracks").off("mouseleave focusout");
  } else {
    $(".barracks").tooltip("close");
    $(".barracks").tooltip("disable");
  }
});
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://www.orfonline.org/public/uploads/posts/image/Indian_Army.jpg" class="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded float-start max-width: 100%;" alt="infantry" title="Infantry">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://media.gettyimages.com/id/50604040/photo/indian-army-machine-gunners-at-base-camp-in-shamsharbara-mts-bordering-pakistan-on-lookout-for.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=1xtLbCtkQ4ak12Azk_dUbtmYdI2rJyo3iz6SNXR7W8U=" class="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block max-width: 100%;" alt="gunner" title="Gunner">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://swarajya.gumlet.io/swarajya/2023-01/992bc74c-0afa-4509-b8c4-148f0faf3e89/acccccc.jpeg?w=610&q=50&compress=true&format=auto" class="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block max-width: 100%;" alt="pilot" title="Pilot">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 thumb">
  <img src="https://www.hsfc.gov.in/UploadFiles/Astronaut/Astronaut5092985885922926595.jpg" class="barracks" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid rounded float-end max-width: 100%;" alt="astronaut" title="Astronaut">
</div>



